# PyVista: 3D Gaussian Smoothing of PolyData

Tags: python, 3d, surface, gaussianblur, pyvista

I would like to replicate the example here https://docs.pyvista.org/version/stable/examples/01-filter/gaussian-smoothing.html using my own data but trying to apply the `gaussian_smooth()` method to my `ImageData` results in `MissingDataError: No data available.` (but works for the example). I'm guessing I need to pass my scalar field to `ImageData` but I'm not sure with what attribute I do this.

Some potentially helpful code:

```
# create a uniform grid to sample the function with
n = 40
x_min, y_min, z_min = [np.min(q) - 0.25*np.absolute(np.min(q)) for q in [tmp[tmp[:,3]==1, 0], tmp[tmp[:,3]==1, 1], tmp[tmp[:,3]==1, 2]]]
x_max, y_max, z_max = [np.max(q) + 0.25*np.absolute(np.max(q)) for q in [tmp[tmp[:,3]==1, 0], tmp[tmp[:,3]==1, 1], tmp[tmp[:,3]==1, 2]]]
grid = pv.ImageData(
    dimensions=(n, n, n),
    spacing=( (x_max - x_min) / n, 
              (y_max - y_min) / n,
              (z_max - z_min) / n),
    origin=(x_min, y_min, z_min),
)

smooth_grid = grid.gaussian_smooth(std_dev=3.0)
```

My question: How can I successfully perform a `gaussian_smooth` on my `ImageData`

Comment: This isn't a MRE.  It cannot be run.  But it looks like you are only creating a mesh while `gaussian_smooth` operates on the data on a mesh.  You need to add data to the mesh, for example: `grid["mydata"] = data_to_be_smoothed`

Comment: @MatthewFlamm I think that is the essence of my question though. What attribute should `mydata` be? I thought `field_data` would work but the PyVista example (`brain.vtk`) doesn't seem to have this defined either (yet I can `guassian_smooth` it.

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.pyvista.org/version/stable/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.ImageDataFilters.gaussian_smooth.html#pyvista.ImageDataFilters.gaussian_smooth) says "_This filter only supports point data_". So you need `point_data`, the same amount of scalars as the points in your image. Field data are specifically data that aren't spatially referenced, they are just metadata associated with your mesh in general. But you are talking about `PolyData` in your question title so without a [mcve] this is extra confusing.

Comment: `grid["mydata"] = array` and `grid.point_data["my_data"] = array` are equivalent when `array` has a first dimension equal to the number of points.